# CocoaPods configuration AFnetworking iOS

Tags: ios, afnetworking, cocoapods

I am about to install CocoaPods and  AFNetworking. I have got this error. I always try everything of my Podfile.

```
workspace ' path/to/AFService.xcworkspace '
source ' https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git '
platform: ios, ' 8.0 '
target ' AFService ' do
    pod ' AFNetworking ' ' ~ > 3.0'
end
```

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

you can clear the podfile and only keep pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.1.0'

Comment: same error "The dependency `AFNetworking (~> 3.1.0)` is not used in any concrete target."

Comment: make sure your pods is the latest version and try this:platform :ios, '8.0'
target "targetName" do
pod 'AFNetworking'
end